# At most one element <fusing> with namespace 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution' was expected, but 2 were found

Tags: android, android-manifest, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I'm getting this error because two dynamic features declare `dist:fusing`.

```
At most one element <fusing> with namespace 
'http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution' 
was expected, but 2 were found.
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I duplicated that tag in my block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution">

    <dist:module
        dist:instant="false"
        dist:title="@string/some_title">
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" /> <!-- there is one here -->
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:on-demand />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="false" /> <!-- remove this!!! -->
    </dist:module>
</manifest>
```